# ¿Cómo puedo acumular el resultado de un input y sumarlo en PHP?

Tags: php

Necesito realizar un programa en PHP que haga lo siguiente:

Realizar la operación: `$operar = $cantidad * $precio;`, y luego que de click en el botón se realice el calculo, y en caso de qué haya un resultado previamente se realice la suma de los mismos.

Mi código:

```
$precio = $_POST['prec_articulo'];

session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION['operar'])) {
    $_SESSION['operar'] = 0;
}

$operarExistente = $_SESSION['operar'];
$operar = $operarExistente + ($cantidad * $precio);
echo $operar;
```

Comment: Bienvenido Julián, pásate por la [ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y revisa como [elaborar una buena pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), si pones el código de lo que llevas hasta ahora y explicas que has intentado y con que resultados, será más fácil que alguien te conteste y obtendrás respuestas mucho más rápido.

Comment: Mmm... una forma fácil de guardar el valor podría ser usando una variable de sesión

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sin sesiones:  Usas otro input para ir llevando el valor acumulado.

```
<?php

$acumulado = intval(@$_POST['acumulado']);
$cantidad = intval(@$_POST['cantidad']);
$precio = intval(@$_POST['precio']);

$acumulado = $acumulado + $cantidad*$precio;

?>

<form method="post"> 
    Llevas acumulado <input type="text" readonly name="acumulado" value="<?=$acumulado?>" />
    <br/>
    <input type="text" name="cantidad" value="<?=$cantidad?>" /> x <input type="text" name="precio" value="<?=$precio?>" /> 
    
    <input type="submit" value="calcular">
</form>
```

Comment: Llevaba mucho tiempo intentando resolver el problema y solo tu solución me sirvió, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

*Esta respuesta es de antes de que se cambiara la pregunta

---

Utiliza una variable se sesión para guardar el valor ya existente:

```
session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION['operar'])) {
  $_SESSION['operar'] = 0;
}

$operarExistente = $_SESSION['operar'];

$operar = $operarExistente + ($cantidad * $precio);
```

Comment: La variable `$_SESSION['operar']` nunca obtiene un valor.